# How to see which button is activated / determine right buttons are activated on python tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm making a game that finding seven right buttons(It has a fixed answer) among 12 buttons by using tkinter. There are a total of 12 buttons, and only if all seven of them are clicked will win the game.

I'm curious about how to make the window to see which button is activated or inactivated, and how to make a function to determine whether one wins or loses. (when seven **specific** buttons are activated, it wins.)

++

```
game1=tkinter.Tk()
game1.title("Test")
game1.geometry("600x450")

button1 = Button(game1, text=' 1 ', fg='black', bg='red', 
                     height=3, width=10) 
button1.place(x=0,y=300)


button2 = Button(game1, text=' 2 ', fg='black', bg='red', 
                     height=3, width=10) 
button2.place(x=100,y=300)

game1.mainloop()
```

This is the first time using tkinter on python so actually I stopped after writing this really basic code.

The player can choose seven buttons until player itself clicks the "finish" button. (after click that button, player cannot modify anything.)

At first, I thought if I declare "num" and +=1 on that when the right buttons are clicked, but this trial failed because the player can choose whether one activates or inactivates until until player itself clicks the "finish" button. So I thought that this code needs the way to check the **final statements** of the buttons.

Is there any ways to use something like "if" statements on tkinter? (if players choose right seven buttons, so it is found that they're activated --> then player wins.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. There are many possible answers, but it depends on how you've defined the buttons and exactly how you are tracking whether they have been clicked or not.

Comment: It's possible, but wouldn't something like Checkbutton widgets be a lot more appropriate for this?

Comment: Read about [command=](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#patterns) and [`relief=`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#Tkinter.Button.config-method)

Comment: @BryanOakley Hello, I edited my questions but actually I totally could not wrote the exact code I wanted, so I only thought deeply about the way to solve the problem. I also wrote the way I've thought. Thanks.

Comment: @Novel Hello, actually I also came up with that idea after I posted the question. Is there a good way to use the check button? Thanks.

Comment: Event based programming is a challenge for new programmers, and this is the case on this question. Instead of writing a complicated program with extra logic, first try to understand how the tkinter api works. For example, to see how you can connect the click of a button to a function you wrote, see tkinters hello world example.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT - I've updated the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from random import sample

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Buttons")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        row_count = 3
        column_count = 4

        self.winning_buttons_count = 7
        assert 0 < self.winning_buttons_count <= row_count * column_count
        winning_buttons_numbers = sample(range(0, row_count * column_count), k=self.winning_buttons_count)

        self.selected_buttons_count = 0
        self.selected_button_color = "gray"
        self.correct_button_color = "green"
        self.incorrect_button_color = "red"
        self.missed_button_color = "orange"
        self.default_button_color = tk.Button().cget("bg")

        def on_press(button):
            color = button.cget("bg")
            if color == self.default_button_color and self.selected_buttons_count < self.winning_buttons_count:
                button.configure(bg=self.selected_button_color)
                button.configure(relief=tk.SUNKEN)
                self.selected_buttons_count += 1
            elif color == self.selected_button_color:
                button.configure(bg=self.default_button_color)
                button.configure(relief=tk.RAISED)
                self.selected_buttons_count -= 1

        def check_win():
            selected_winning_count = 0
            for button in self.buttons:
                is_selected = button.cget("bg") == self.selected_button_color and \
                              button.cget("relief") == tk.SUNKEN
                is_winning = button.number in winning_buttons_numbers

                if is_selected:
                    if is_winning:
                        button.configure(bg=self.correct_button_color)
                        selected_winning_count += 1
                    else:
                        button.configure(bg=self.incorrect_button_color)
                else:
                    if is_winning:
                        button.configure(bg=self.missed_button_color)

            if selected_winning_count == self.winning_buttons_count:
                self.finish_button.configure(text="You won!")
            else:
                self.finish_button.configure(text="Incorrect.")

        self.buttons = []

        for row in range(row_count):
            for column in range(column_count):
                button = tk.Button(self, text=" " * 8)
                button.grid(row=row, column=column)
                button.number = (row * column_count) + column
                button.configure(command=lambda b=button: on_press(b))
                self.buttons.append(button)

        vertical_line = ttk.Separator(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        vertical_line.grid(row=0, column=column_count+1, rowspan=row_count, sticky="ns", padx=(8, 8))

        self.finish_button = tk.Button(self, text="Did I win?", command=check_win)
        self.finish_button.grid(row=row_count//2, column=column_count+2)

def main():

    application = Application()
    application.mainloop()

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help! It is a good idea to make button's statement instantly "disabled" when clicking it. I'll try writing a new code by using this method. Thanks. ++ I've edited the question in detail, if it is not too much trouble,  could you give another advice about the code?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment until now. I've updated my original post.

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped me a lot. I've learned a lot by studying this code. Thanks a lot!